# Chart Js function (Chart.js) is stuck in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to use Chart.js in my HTML document(main.html) by calling the the javascript function form a separate javascript file (home.js).
The HTML looks as follows:

```
{% block head %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/home.js"></script>
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
<div>
    <canvas id='myChart'></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    Chart(data, document.getElementById('myChart'))
</script>
```

The js file looks as follows:

```
function Chart(data, ctx){
    console.log("JS")
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I do that it somehow keeps executing the the function (ie. stuck in a loop, I checked that by using console.log('JS'). I did not figure out why it keeps doing that. The chart is never displayed.
If I add the function directly in the html in a  tag it works flawlessly, but I'd rather want the js separate from the html.
I use flask as web framework and that is where the variable 'data' is coming from. Any tips or ideas?

Thanks and regards

PS: I don't use 'data' at the moment because I don't even get the chart running (it will be the result of db query later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, two problems unrelated to your infinite loop problem:

1. In main.html, the `data` param you are sending to Chart.js is undefined. Presumably you will fix that in your actual code.
2. In the selector you send to Chart.js, you are sending the canvas – `document.getElementById('myChart')` – when you should be sending the canvas context – `document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d')`

Once those are fixed, you could potentially be rendering a chart, but you get an infinite loop because you have called your own function `Chart` when that's also the name of the Chart.js function (where it says `var myChart = new Chart(ctx, ...)`. Just change your function name to something else.

Here's an example where I just put in an empty array for `data` and changed your function name to `drawChart`.

```js
function drawChart(data, ctx){
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}

drawChart([], document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='myChart'></canvas>
```

NB: The script error that shows up in the console log is because of cross-origin scripting on StackOverflow and is something you can fix on your own site.

Comment: Thank you very much, I totally missed that. Data is an element which is provided from flask later